# How to exclude a queryset of users from all users in django?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am developing a django rest api using the DRF and in one of my views I override the get_queryset function:

```
class UserSearchListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        current_user_friends = Friend.objects.friends(self.request.user)
        all_users = User.objects.all()
        # from the all_users queryset I need to remove the current_user_friends queryset.
        # Should the exclude function be used?
```

From the `all_users` queryset I need to exclude the user making the request and the same user's friends which are contained in the `current_user_friends` queryset. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
all_users = [1,2,3,4]
current_user_friends = [1,2]
print list(set(all_users)-set(current_user_friends))
print [user for user in all_users if user not in current_user_friends]
print filter(lambda user: user not in current_user_friends, all_users)
```

Comment: Actually they are all querysets not lists, sorry.

Comment: Can you convert the quertsets to lists and then back?

Comment: Well probably, but there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage values_list and the .exclude() method of QuerySets to achieve what you wish:

```
current_friends_excluded = all_users.exclude(id__in=current_user_friends.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

To exclude the user making the request, you can retrieve it from the request object or pass an identifying value in the request to retrieve it and include it in a separate .exclude().